# Is the [minorities] tag correctly annotated?

Tags: discussion, tags

Coming from this [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74739/are-there-any-multi-country-eu-polls-on-the-russian-language-policies-of-former), where `[minorities]` was removed, incorrectly in my view.  But then looking at the tag's definition, maybe the removal was justified, because minorities is defined in too narrow and specific a way?

[Questions List header](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minorities):

> Questions about categories of people with a **relative disadvantage compared to those in dominant social groups**.

I could be a minority in numbers, doesn't mean I am disadvantaged.  For example, are white South Africans not a minority then?

What about using [Merriam Webster's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minority)?

> a: a part of a population differing from others in some characteristics and often subjected to differential treatment
> "the country's ethnic minorities"
>
> b: a member of a minority group
> "an effort to hire more minorities"

Comment: You beat me to it. I think the present tag info is based on Wikipedia, but that wiki page also says there's a controversy regarding the def. And further down the page it gives a contrary one (no discrimination needed) for "national minority": "A national minority is a social group within a state that differs from the majority and/or dominant population in terms of ethnicity, language, culture, or religion, but also it also tends to have a close link with a specific territory from which the minority social group originates." That's cited from the UN, so probably not that controversial.

Comment: How about splitting first half of MW?  *A part of a population differing from others in some characteristics.  This group is often, but does not have to be, subjected to differential treatment.*

Comment: So a possible solution would be to create another tag "national-minority", but I'm not sure the proliferation would be too helpful...

Comment: No, I'd keep the same tag, but just remove or deemphasize the condition that they *need* to be disadvantaged.  That's just SJW'ing a tag needlessly.  Of course, they are *often* discriminated against, but that's not a condition to being a minority due to lower numbers.

Comment: Not a regular here, but I noticed [tag:discrimination] tag also exists, so I guess defining [tag:minorities] tag more neutrally won't hurt, and when the question is both about *discrimination against minorities*, then both tags can and should be used.

Comment: Surely the question is: what is the tag intended to represent. Are women a minority? Does it include religion, sexuality, etc, or is it purely the national minority (i.e. ethnic minority) sense quoted in a comment above.

Answer (score 4):

FWTW, the UN doesn't seem to include the necessity of discrimination in [their def](https://www.un.org/en/fight-racism/vulnerable-groups/minorities):

> Who are minorities under international law?
>
> Adopted by consensus in 1992, the purpose of the United Nations Minorities Declaration is the promotion and protection of the rights of persons belonging to national or ethnic, religious and linguistic minorities and as such to contribute to the political and social stability of States in which they live.
>
> There is no internationally agreed definition as to who is a minority. The existence of a minority is a question of fact and carries both objective factors (such as the existence of a shared ethnicity, language or religion) and subjective factors (including that individuals must identify themselves as belonging to a national or ethnic, religious or linguistic minority group).
>
> Already in 1948, the General Assembly declared that the United Nations could not remain indifferent to the fate of minorities.
>
> The Declaration was inspired by Article 27 of the International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights, which is the most widely accepted legally binding provision on minorities.

The latter reads:

> In those States in which ethnic, religious or linguistic minorities exist, persons belonging to such minorities shall not be denied the right, in community with the other members of their group, to enjoy their own culture, to profess and practise their own religion, or to use their own language.

Likewise, they have a [brochure](https://www.ohchr.org/Documents/Issues/Minorities/Booklet_Minorities_English.pdf) which has this

[image]

> States must protect the existence of minorities.

in bold. So that desideratum would make no sense (would be *malum in se*) if minorities could only exist as longs as subjected to "relative disadvantage". The UN def is clearly at odds with some others given in Wikipedia (which do exist) that use "relative disadvantage". Wikipedia's "relative disadvantage" def is cited to

> Healey, Joseph F. (2 March 2018). Race, ethnicity, gender, & class : the sociology of group conflict and change. Stepnick, Andi,, O'Brien, Eileen, 1972– (Eighth ed.). Thousand Oaks, California.

I'm guessing that's an American textbook.

MW's "differential treatment" appears to try to straddle these, as "differential treatment" is not necessarily a disadvantage.

Comment: OK, but that doesn't tell us what should be in the tag description either.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: I realize that, but all that info seemed too much to cram in comments. The issue remaining is that "differential treatment" might not quite cover all breadth of differences that UN sees in practice for minorities, so we might be back here at some point with someone removing the tag because a minority in the UN (eclectic)  sense isn't "proven" to be subjected to differential treatment...

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica; I suppose the saving grace there is that MW qualifies that with "often'.